# How to use a str from list as variable in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read some data from a file, and use the values of the file in a specific row as values for my dictionary.
One of the values in the file is a variable (filename) that is already configured in my code, but when I'm trying to use the value in the dictionary it's represented as str.
is it possible to somehow represent it as a variable name?

Text File:

```
Query Tests
csv_name_1,Product,MAIL,Protocol,IMAP4,Total in DB
csv_name_1,Product,MAIL,Protocol,IMAP4,Total in DB
csv_name_1,Product,MAIL,Protocol,IMAP4,Total in DB
csv_name_1,Product,MAIL,Protocol,IMAP4,Total in DB
csv_name_1,Product,MAIL,Protocol,IMAP4,Total in DB
```

Already existed variable

```
csv_name_1 = "%s/gpdb_%s.csv" % (tmp_dir, today_wo_clock)
csv_name_2 = "%s/gpdb_aa_%s.csv" % (tmp_dir, today_wo_clock)
```

What I'm trying to run:

```
lookup = 'csv_name_'
with open('Excel_Mapping.txt') as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if lookup in line:
            data = line.split(sep=',')
            if len(data) >= 8:
                lov = data
                row = {'csv_name': lov[0], 'col1_name': lov[1], 'col1_val': lov[2],
                       'col2_name': lov[3], 'col2_val': lov[4], 'col3_name': lov[5], 'col3_val': int(lov[6]),
                       'result_col_name': lov[7], 'sanity_excel_name': sanity_excel_name, 'row': num}
```

Expected result: csv_name_1 passed as variable and the code using already defined variable with this name.

```
row = {'csv_name': csv_name_1, 'col1_name': lov[1], 'col1_val': lov[2],
                           'col2_name': lov[3], 'col2_val': lov[4], 'col3_name': lov[5], 'col3_val': int(lov[6]),
                           'result_col_name': lov[7], 'sanity_excel_name': sanity_excel_name, 'row': num}
```

Actual result: csv_name_1 passed as string and of course a failure in execution cause no such file

```
row = {'csv_name': 'csv_name_1', 'col1_name': lov[1], 'col1_val': lov[2],
                           'col2_name': lov[3], 'col2_val': lov[4], 'col3_name': lov[5], 'col3_val': int(lov[6]),
                           'result_col_name': lov[7], 'sanity_excel_name': sanity_excel_name, 'row': num}
```

Comment: `row = {'csv_name': globals().get(lov[0]), 'col1_name': ...}`

Comment: Thanks, it works :)
Already tried globals but probably by the wrong way.